# Creating Excel with multple sheets with execute sql task

Tags: excel, file, ssis, creation, ssis-2008

In SSIS, you can create an Excel file with a "Execute SQL Task", if your connection is an Excel connetion. In "SQL Statement" put a create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `EXAMPLE_SHEET`    
(    
    `COLUMN_1` NVARCHAR(200),
    `COLUMN_2` INTEGER    
)
```

And the Excel file is created! (if file already exists, throw error) but, how i can create an excel like this but with several sheets??

(EDIT TO POST A SOLUTION)

I have tried to put 3 "create table" in 3 different "execute sql task" and it works. From what I have verified, the task gives error if it tries to generate a sheet that already exists (something totally logical).

Comment: Did you try two `CREATE TABLE` statements separated by semi-colon?

Comment: I tried it but not works